# Convert Jsonstring from Web request to String

Tags: android, json, replace, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

I tried to parse json from Web request in Xamarin Android application. But i am getting the below json string

```
[{\"type1\":val1,\"type2\":\"val2",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":val4},
{\"type1\":val1,\"type2\":\"val2",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":val4}]
```

**How to convert this into string like below**

```
[{"type1":"val1","type2":"val2","type3":"val3","type4":"val4"},
{"type1":"val1","type2":"val2","type3":"val3","type4":"val4"}]
```

Comment: How are you getting the JSON? Are you sure the server isn't sending the string escaped like that? There is nothing inherent in Android or Xamarin that would cause that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get the string value by copying the C# runtime value? If so, it looks to be correct with some minor errors.

```
[{\"type1\":val1,\"type2\":\"val2",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":val4},
{\"type1\":val1,\"type2\":\"val2",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":val4}]
```

Should probable be:

```
[{\"type1\":\"val1\",\"type2\":\"val2\",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":\"val4\"},
{\"type1\":\"val1\",\"type2\":\"val2\",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":\"val4\"}]
```

Some of the val*'s didn't have quotes at all and the type2 was missing \ on the quote.

Is it your own web service? Did your web request specify JSON as format? If the service is running JavaScript, does it call JSON.stringify(...) to normalize the JSON object? If you are using MVC or other MS technology make sure you are not wrapping the response in double JSON (f.e. returning a string by the controller where the string is JSON serialized as this will cause the doubling).

Good tool to verify the JSON returned by the web service is [PostMan](http://getpostman.com/). If it also returns the string with the \'s in it then something is wrong with the service itself.

Here is a little tester for Android with JSON.Net serializer:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Util;

namespace JsonTest
{
    public class TypeClass 
    {
        public string type1 { get; set; }
        public string type2 { get; set; }
        public string type3 { get; set; }
        public string type4 { get; set; }
    }

    [Activity (Label = "JsonTest", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        private const string JsonText = "[{\"type1\":\"val1\",\"type2\":\"val2\",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":\"val4\"}," +
                                      "{\"type1\":\"val1\",\"type2\":\"val2\",\"type3\":\"val3\",\"type4\":\"val4\"}]";



        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate
            {
                var resp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TypeClass>>(JsonText);

                foreach (var t in resp)
                {
                    Log.Info("Type1", t.type1);
                    Log.Info("Type2", t.type2);
                    Log.Info("Type3", t.type3);
                    Log.Info("Type4", t.type4);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String jsonString = json.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Comment: in Xamarin Android, there is no method like string.replaceall. Also i tried Replace method with this "\\\\", not working